# htaccess will not rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

my htaccess has a number of rewrite rules, and for some reason will not rewrite/work:

Example
Context: when you go to sign up you click sign up and then on click of the submit it takes you to the link: www.sanchexpaycut.com/home

the rule:
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,30})/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]

what the rule would/should output: http://sanchezpaycut.com/index.php?page=home

what happens: 404 not found error

with error log: [Sun May 26 09:10:20 2013] [error] [client 24.91.118.174] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/patmccoy.me/sanchez/home, referer: http://sanchezpaycut.com/

also does the same thing with the pages at the bottom of the names:

link: http://sanchezpaycut[dot]com/page_2#listing
Rule:
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,30})/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]

what should happen: http://sanchezpaycut[dot]com/index.php?page=page_2#listing
what happens: 404

Any help would be awesome thanks

Server info: mediatemple dv - mod rewrite is checked on and installed correctly

htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

DirectoryIndex index.php


RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,30})/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ index.php?page=$1&s=$2&o=$3 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,30})/([^/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([^/]+)?$ index.php?page=$1&s=$2&o=$3&p=$4 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,30})/([^/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([^/]+)?$ index.php?page=$1&s=$2&o=$3&p=$4&q=$5 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,30})/([^/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([^/]+)?$ index.php?page=$1&s=$2&o=$3&p=$4&q=$5&r=$6 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,30})/([^/]+)?$ index.php?page=$1&s=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,30})/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,30})?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404
```

Comment: Could you give complete information, and do some debugging? what is your complete .htaccess? have installed the apache module correctly? (does any rewrite work at all), does your htaccess work at all, etc.

Comment: just updated... and thanks for looking into it

Answer (score -1):

I give an example from my webpage. This is my `.htacces` file and it is working good.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f 
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]

RewriteRule ^desene/categoria-(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?action=selectcategorie&categorie=$1&pag=$2
RewriteRule ^desene/categoria-(.*) index.php?action=selectcategorie&categorie=$1
RewriteRule ^top-desene/categoria-(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?action=top-desene-categoria&categorie=$1&pag=$2
RewriteRule ^top-desene/categoria-(.*) index.php?action=top-desene-categoria&categorie=$1
RewriteRule ^desene/tehnica-(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?action=selecttehnica&tehnica=$1&pag=$2
RewriteRule ^desene/tehnica-(.*) index.php?action=selecttehnica&tehnica=$1
RewriteRule ^top-desene/tehnica-(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?action=top-desene-tehnica&tehnica=$1&pag=$2
RewriteRule ^top-desene/tehnica-(.*) index.php?action=top-desene-tehnica&tehnica=$1
RewriteRule ^contact index.php?action=contact
RewriteRule ^login index.php?action=login
RewriteRule ^desen/(.*)$ index.php?action=desen&iddesen=$1
```